# Custom module and block API

Tags: blocks

Have followed all the steps at http://www.packtpub.com/comment/reply/7089 to create a custom module.

I am able to create it and it is showing under the Modules and is getting enabled. However as the purpose of this module is to create a new block it is not doing so. Its not showing under the Structure/Blocks. Any reasons?

```
name = First
description = A first module.
package = Drupal 7 Development
core = 7.x
files[] = first.module

;dependencies[] = autoload
;php = 5.2
```

```
/**
 * @file
 * A module exemplifying Drupal coding practices and APIs.
 *
 * This module provides a block that lists all of the
 * installed modules. It illustrates coding standards,
 * practices, and API use for Drupal 7.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 */
function first_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#first') {
    return t('A demonstration module.');
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function first_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['list_modules'] = array(
    'info' => t('A listing of all of the enabled modules.'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function first_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'list_modules') {
    $list = module_list();

    $theme_args = array('items' => $list, 'type' => 'ol');
    $content = theme('item_list', $theme_args);

    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('Enabled Modules'),
      'content' => $content,
    );

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, `files[]` is only necessary when a module implements PHP classes.

Answer (score -1):

Let you try with this code. Clear performance cache.

```
function example_block_info() {
  $blocks['my-block-id'] = array(
    'info' => t('Block Name'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view().
 */
function example_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my-block-id':
      $block['subject'] = t('Block Name');
      $block['content'] = example_contents();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * custom html block
 * @return string
 */
function example_contents() {
  return '
    </p><div class="body">
      Hello World, this is a example custom Block
    </div><p>
  ';
}
```

For more info see this http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/how-create-basic-block-code-new-drupal-7

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work.